# Integrate Google Analytics Dashboard in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have found the following site on google: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/demos/embed-api
Telling me about the Google API Demo.

Now how do I implement these things in a page in Rails, this is not clear to me.

What we want is to show a few "Dashboards"(Page views today, etc ..) in Rails Admin or a Separate page in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a Javascript library, so you would create new a view and paste some HTML and JS into it. You'll have to make sure it works with your application layout. The [Embed API - Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide) guide shows the code to get a dashboard up and running.

Comment: ajw! That's just want I needed :) I'm going to leave this topic open for a while and post my findings.

Comment: Hey Vinozio, I am trying to do exactly the same thing as you have in my app currently as seen on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915871/including-google-analytics-embed-api-third-party-dashboard-example-javascript-in) and having some trouble loading the dependent JS files. How did you solve this issue?

Comment: @stcho we outsourced the implementation of this. Sorry!