# Including Google Analytics Embed API third party dashboard example javascript in my Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dashboard

I am following this example here for the [Google Analytics Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) to implement a GA third party dashboard via Chart.js in my app and I am having trouble on `Step 3` where we are including all the javascript libraries.

I was able to load the Embed API in my `application.js` as so

```
(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));

//= require /public/javascript/Chart.min.j
//= require /public/javascript/moment.min.js
//= require /public/javascript/embed-api/date-range-selector.js
//= require /public/javascript/embed-api/active-users.js
```

It shows in `Networks` section in the dev tools that the `cb=gapi.loaded_0` is getting loaded. However, the other libraries are not. `Charts.min.js` and `moments.min.js` are available online but I wan't sure where I can find `embed-api/date-range-selector.js` or `embed-api/active-users.js` to retrieve into my app?

**EDIT1**
Found the files here: https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I believe the Rails asset pipeline needs to have some sort of `//= require_self` or something like that to ensure the code in the current file is included. It looks to me like the loading snippet in that file isn't being run or is being run in the wrong order.

It's probably easier and simpler to just save it into a separate file so you can ensure the order is correct.

```
// File: /public/javascript/embed-api-snippet.js

(function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
  g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
  js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
}(window,document,'script'));
```

Then put the rest of your code in a setup file like so:

```
// File: /public/javascript/embed-api-setup.js

gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
   container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
   clientid: 'REPLACE WITH YOUR CLIENT ID',
  });

  // the rest of the setup code...

});
```

Now your manifest should look like this:

```
//= require /public/javascript/embed-api-snippet.js

//= require /public/javascript/Chart.min.js
//= require /public/javascript/moment.min.js
//= require /public/javascript/embed-api/date-range-selector.js
//= require /public/javascript/embed-api/active-users.js

//= require /public/javascript/embed-api-setup.js
```

Also, you said:

> This is talking about the gapi.analytics.auth.authorize section which I believe is part of the embed-api/active-user.js

Actually, the `gapi.analytics.auth.authorize` part is not in the `ActiveUsers` component, the auth part is something you have to write yourself (because the client ID needs to be specific to you), and it should go in the `embed-api-setup.js` file as I've described above.

The setup code for the [example you're referencing](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) can be [found here](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/master/templates/embed-api/code/_third-party-visualizations.js).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will try implementing it this way right now and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Regarding the `REPLACE WITH YOUR CLIENT ID` where in Google Analytics can I find my client ID to put in there? Also, I want other users other than myself to be able to retrieve their own GA Data and would hardcoding it not allow it to do that? Meaning should I place a variable in there instead?

Comment: Check out [this guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide). The client ID is not an analytics thing, it's a Google thing. It is tied to a project which controls things like access and request quota and the like.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So I realized the libraries are indeed getting loaded because when I removed the initial code block as you suggested from the `application.js` and ran it again without it there and without it included, it throws an error that state `couldn't find file '/public/javascript/Chart.min.j'` which seems to mean it could before and so loaded into our app. Is there a way to test for sure if it is or not?

Comment: If the case above is true then it would mean the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined` is the problem here, which must be due to my `clientid`. I created one with the options `Web Application` and added my local url. I'll be updating the main post with this info.

Comment: If `gapi.analytics.auth` if defined then you should be good. Also, check the network tab of your dev tools to ensure `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` is being downloaded.

Comment: I do see the `cb=gapi.loaded_0` in the `Networks` section of the dev tools. I updated the post as well.

Comment: At this point I think the only advice I can give is to start with the [super simple example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide) in the documentation and work your way from there. The example you're trying to build is more complex and thus has more moving parts that could be the cause of your troubles.

Comment: Hi Philip, actually I was able to get past the error while working on it since we last talked! I can now see the "Access Google Analytics" which launches the creation of the charts. Thanks for all your help. I am still figuring out how to get the `embed-apis` included in my app which I updated in the post above, and I ran into another error, which I feel as though it would be best to open a new question regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

I did about the same thing in Rails Admin.

First of all I did this [Rails Admin Customization: embed html view into dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379017/rails-admin-customization-embed-html-view-into-dashboard) but I think it can be any view you like.

In this .html.erb file I have inserted the GA code from their website:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Embed API Demos &mdash; Pure HTML Dashboards</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/main.css">

  <script src="../assets/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../assets/ga-auth.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../assets/ga-dashboard.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../assets/ga-chart.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../assets/ga-viewpicker.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../assets/ga-datepicker.html">


</head>
<body>

  <header class="Banner">
    <h1 class="Banner-title">
      <a href="/">Embed API Demos</a>
      <em>Pure HTML Dashboards</em>
    </h1>
    <ga-auth clientid="INSERTYOURIDHERE"></gauth>
  </header>

  <ga-dashboard>

    <section id="controls">
      <ga-viewpicker></ga-viewpicker>
      <ga-datepicker
        startDate="30daysAgo"
        endDate="14daysAgo">
      </ga-datepicker>
    </section>

    <section id="charts">
      <ga-chart
        title="Timeline"
        type="LINE"
        metrics="ga:sessions"
        dimensions="ga:date">
      </ga-chart>

      <ga-chart
        title="Sessions (by country)"
        type="GEO"
        metrics="ga:sessions"
        dimensions="ga:country">
      </ga-chart>

      <ga-chart
        title="Top Browsers"
        type="COLUMN"
        metrics="ga:sessions"
        dimensions="ga:browser"
        sort="-ga:sessions"
        maxResults="5">
      </ga-chart>

      <ga-chart
        title="Top pages"
        type="TABLE"
        metrics="ga:sessions"
        dimensions="ga:pagePath"
        sort="-ga:sessions"
        maxResults="8">
      </ga-chart>
    </section>

  </ga-dashboard>

<footer class="SourceLink">
  <a
  href="https://github.com/googleanalytics/embed-api-demos/blob/master/site/6-pure-html-dashboards.html">
  View source on Github</a>
  &nbsp;&#8594;
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Next I added all the GA JS and CSS and HTML to Vendor:

[image]

I hope this helps :)

**EDIT1**: More information about GA Dashboarding is found here: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/

Comment: The examples files you're referencing here are no longer being used. The [`<google-analytics>`](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/polymer-elements/) polymer element is the currently supported version of the original pure HTML dashboard example.

Comment: @PhilipWalton where to download?

Comment: The link I had above had download information. Here's the github repo: https://github.com/googlewebcomponents/google-analytics/